# Como hacer un GLM?

Tags: r

Tengo un conjunto de datos llamados *uno* Esta formado por 1 variable independiente y 8 variables dependientes:

```
 0.73 25.0 27.2 23.1 31.6 67    46   82  78.1         15
 0.63 10.0 28.4 24.6 32.9 70    52   82  62.7          8
 0.70 10.0 28.6 24.7 33.8 71    50   85 145.3         16
 0.80 10.0 28.1 24.3 33.2 74    57   85  92.5         12
 0.67  7.5 26.1 22.4 30.9 70    52   82  78.0          8
 0.31 35.0 27.2 23.1 31.6 67    46   82  78.1         15
 0.25 35.0 28.4 24.6 32.9 70    52   82  62.7          8
 0.30 80.0 28.6 24.7 33.8 71    50   85 145.3         16
 0.20 65.0 28.1 24.3 33.2 74    57   85  92.5         12
 0.44 85.0 26.3 23.2 32.2 68    48   81  23.8          7
 0.44 82.5 26.1 22.4 30.9 70    52   82  78.0          8
 0.76 80.0 27.2 23.1 31.6 67    46   82  78.1         15
 0.74 50.0 28.4 24.6 32.9 70    52   82  62.7          8
 0.52 75.0 28.6 24.7 33.8 71    50   85 145.3         16
 0.18 70.0 28.1 24.3 33.2 74    57   85  92.5         12
 0.79 60.0 26.1 22.4 30.9 70    52   82  78.0          8
 0.73 20.0 27.2 23.1 31.6 67    46   82  78.1         15
 0.88 15.0 28.4 24.6 32.9 70    52   82  62.7          8
 0.93 50.0 28.6 24.7 33.8 71    50   85 145.3         16
 0.97 25.0 28.1 24.3 33.2 74    57   85  92.5         12
 0.63 45.0 26.3 23.2 32.2 68    48   81  23.8          7
 0.73 25.0 26.1 22.4 30.9 70    52   82  78.0          6
```

quiero hacer un GLM y obtener los valores de desviacion y de AIC para cada variable
El codigo que uso es el siguiene:

```
require(gam)
require(ISLR)
data(uno)
lm(un~HR.superficie+C.A+T+Tmin+Tmax+HR+HR13h+HR7h+Precp+Dias.precp,data=un)
plot(uno)
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error>
invalid type (list) for variable 'uno'

Como puedo resolver este problea?? Gracias

Comment: El ejemplo del código, más allá del error tipográfico de `data=un`, no parece ser consistente con el error que mencionas, comentas también que tu idea es un modelo `glm` pero el código corresponde a uno lineal común. Trata de corregir estos temas en tu pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: otro tema, con `plot(uno)` ¿que es lo que buscas? ¿qué datos tiene `uno`?  ¿no será el modelo lo que quieres gráficar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeramente, hubiese sido mejor si colocas el nombre de las variables de tu data frame `ùno`.

Omitiendo aquello. Al querer correr el modelo de regresión lineal, en tu código. Estas considerando mal al data frame, estas considerando `un`, en vez de `uno`. Por tanto, debería de ser así.

```
reg_lineal<-lm(un~HR.superficie+C.A+T+Tmin+Tmax+HR+HR13h+HR7h+Precp+Dias.precp,
               data=uno)
```

Luego, corres un `plot()` pero no puedes colocar como entrada un data frame. Por tanto si quieres ver los cuatro gráficos que brinda R tendrías que especificar la regresión lineal.

```
plot(reg_lineal)
```

Ahora si quieres hacer una regresión GLM. Sólo tienes que cambiar las funciones `lm()` por `glm()`, y luego especificar la familia, por ejemplo si quieres hacer una regresión lineal  tendrías que especificarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
reg_lineal2<-glm(un~HR.superficie+C.A+T+Tmin+Tmax+HR+HR13h+HR7h+Precp+Dias.precp,
               data=uno, family = gaussian(link = "identity"))
```

Tu pregunta no es nada clara, te recomiendo redefinir tu pregunta y brindar mayor información.